# Exercise 4.4 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> $f$ and $g$ are continuous mapping of a metric space X into metric space Y and $E$ is dense subset of X.
> (a)Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in f(X).
> (b)If $g(p)=f(p)$ for all $p\in E$, prove that $g(p)=f(p)$ for all $p\in X$.

**My attempt:**
Part(b)
since $g(p)=f(p)$ for all $p\in E$, we have $f(E)=g(E)$. So their limit points are equal.$\overline{f(E)} = f(E) \cup (f(E))^\prime$ and $\overline{g(E)} =g(E)\cup (g(E))^\prime$. So $\overline{f(E)} = \overline{g(E)}$. $f(E)$ and $g(E)$ are dense in $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ respectively. Thus, $f(X)=g(X)$.

**Question:**

Is this proof correct? I don’t think so, because it doesn’t explicitly show $f(p)=g(p),\forall p \in X$. Can this solution be modified or improve to make it work.

In part(a) how should I show $\overline{f(E)} \subseteq f(X)$?

Comment: It is not correct, because $f(X) = g(X)$ does not imply $f(p) = g(p)$ for all $p$ in $X$. A more natural argument is as follows. Since $E$ is dense, for every point p in $X$ there exist a sequence $e_n$ of points in $E$ that converge to $p$. Also $f(e_n) = g(e_n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What does continuity of $f$ and $g$ tell us about $f(p)$ and $g(p)$?

About your doubt, if $E$ is dense in $X$ then every point of $X$ is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: What if one of the $e_n$ equals to p? then we can’t use theorem 4.2. Can you please prove the last statement(or claim) you made?

Comment: If $e_n = p$ then $p \in E$, since the sequence is made of elements of E. Then, you already know that $f(p) = g(p)$ and you have nothing to prove. About my last claim, it is just the definition of dense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set A set $E$ is dense in $X$ if every point in $X$ is either a point of $E$ or a limit point of $E$.

Comment: Yeah. I was insistent on using thm 4.2, my bad. I am saying of possibility $p \in E$ and $p \in$ X but $p \notin$ limit point of E.

Comment: You said for every point of X that point is in limit point of E

Comment: @user267445 Every point $p$ of $E$ is trivially a limit point of $E$ since the sequence $e_n = p$ is a sequence of points of $E$ that converges to $p$.

Comment: So you are using this definition of closure: $ \overline{S}=(s | s_n converge to s, & s_n is in S )$

Comment: @user26475 Just read carefully the wikipedia article, it has an answer for all the questions you have made.

Comment: Okay. But I think you have cleared most of my doubts. So thank you for that.